# How to implement Audio Record Quality in android?

Tags: android, audio

I am working on an Android project in which I want the same functionality as the Android native audio recorder. Specifically the sound quality option. I can't use the native recorder, so I'm recording audio using the `AudioRecord` class. How do I process the data coming from the `AudioRecord` class for the quality? Application has three quality defined which I need to implement:

- **Low** - records will have only high pitch sounds,
- **Medium** - records will have some of background sound,
- **High** - everything that reaches at microphone Will be Recorded.

Please suggest some way to do it.

Comment: If I understand you right, you want to filter by the **audio level**. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401455/i-want-to-check-the-loudness-of-voice-in-android and here http://www.doepiccoding.com/blog/?p=195.

Comment: Thank you @TDG I did it by changing the sample rate.